# Mongodb CPU Usage at 100%

Tags: python, mongodb, digital-ocean

I have 2 `python` processes reading/writing to mongodb and the CPU usage on `htop` is usually 100%. Memory usage averages 221 MB out of 491 MB.

From `mongostat`, we have:

[image]

How should I troubleshoot whether its inefficient queries or insufficient resources?

I'm using Digital Ocean's server with 512MB, 1 CPU and 20GB SSD. Is 100% CPU usage normal for such a server?

Comment: Can you post the output of top? Is the CPU usage mostly attributed to `mongod`, your Python processes, or something else? What version of MongoDB is this?

Comment: Indeed most important is to know what your python scripts are doing. Maybe they are blocking each other or thousand other reasons. Best would be to show the TOP output and some pseudo code (or the real one) of your python scripts.